# Modify default option of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to change the default value of 2 columns from 'N' to 'Y' using the below query, but it throws a error. Any idea whats wrong in here. Error: Invalid Alter table option.

```
Alter Table USER
Modify 
CONTACT_FLAG  Default 'Y',
APPROVAL_FLAG Default 'Y' ;
```

Comment: add your datatype between field_name and default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the columns like this

```
alter table
   table_name
modify
   (
      column1_name  column1_datatype,
      column2_name  column2_datatype,
      column3_name  column3_datatype,
      column4_name  column4_datatype
   );
```